# How to get MIME type hitting from URL in android

Tags: android, http, url, mime-types, mime

How to get the MIME type hitting the URL in android,
i have one URL ( http://www.softultima.com/GetQIContent.ashx) in that three type of file can come (Video,Image,GIF)
then how to detect the MIME type

Comment: If you are downloading the file, check the `Content-type` header as part of the download. If you are not downloading the file, issue an HTTP `HEAD` request and check the `Content-type` header of the response.

Comment: i have used the code 
 String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl("http://www.softultima.com/GetQIContent.ashx");
            if (extension != null) {
                type = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
            }
but it is retyring null

Comment: That is because `ashx` is not a recognized file extension. AFAICT, that extension is used for some generic Web handling on Microsoft servers; the exact MIME type of the response would depend on what that Web handlers actually do.

Comment: i want to show the content in my android app coming from that link please suggest

Comment: In the first comment you already got the right suggestion.